# what is a meaning of message "invalid argument to function ms access"

Tags: ms-access

I have a query built on two queries

```
SELECT 
    Natiga_f_half.stu_code, 
    Natiga_f_half.st_set_no, 
    Natiga_s_half.stu_name, 
    [Natiga_f_half]![natiga_sum] + [Natiga_s_half]![natiga_sum] AS final_sum, 
    [Natiga_f_half]![total] + [Natiga_s_half]![Total] AS final_total, 
    IIf(
            [final_total] < (select tot_s from subject_dgree_end  where shoba = [Natiga_f_half]![shoba]) And [final_sum] > 1,
                " /مجموع كلي ",
            IIf(
                    [final_total] < (select tot_s from subject_dgree_end  where shoba = [Natiga_f_half]![shoba]) And [final_sum] = 1, 
                        "/مجموع كلى وله حق اختيار ماده واحده",
                    IIf(
                            [final_total] < (select tot_b from subject_dgree_end  where shoba = [Natiga_f_half]![shoba]) And [final_sum] = 0,
                                "/مجموع كلى وله حق اختيار ماده  اومادتين",
                            ""
                        )
                )
        ) AS total_end, 
    [Natiga_f_half]![natiga] + [Natiga_s_half]![natiga] AS final_natiga, 
    Natiga_f_half.code_kind, 
    Natiga_f_half.kind
FROM 
    Natiga_s_half 
    INNER JOIN 
    Natiga_f_half 
    ON 
    Natiga_s_half.stu_code = Natiga_f_half.stu_code;
```

gave me the error message  `"invalid argument to function ms access"`

---

when I delete

```
"Natiga_s_half.stu_name, [Natiga_f_half]![natiga_sum]+[Natiga_s_half]![natiga_sum] AS final_sum"
```

it works

natiga_sum is total of some fields

Comment: It means you supplied an invalid argument.

Comment: how can i solve the problem

Comment: By not supplying an invalid argument.

Comment: the two sub query work ok and i just sum two fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these contains an invalid value:

```
[Natiga_f_half]![natiga_sum]+[Natiga_s_half]![natiga_sum]
```

To debug, replace one with a zero, then the other, and study the output:

```
[Natiga_f_half]![natiga_sum]+0
```

and

```
0+[Natiga_s_half]![natiga_sum]
```